# Header menu navigates from another page to another to a specific section

Tags: wordpress, elementor

how to do such a redirect. 
I have a menu with "Home" "about us", "customers", "contact" and now, just like I'm on the main page, I have anchored on the same page references to "about us" and "contact" so after clicking I will scroll to section. But I have "clients" on a different page, so redirects me to the other subpage and now from the other one I would like to redirect to the "contact on the main page" section. My site is on wordpress and I use elementor to do it, please help. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Assign the id to the section 
like -->https://prnt.sc/r1ov1y ,id=clients

**link:**  https://(siteUrl/pageUrl)#clients